# Creating Downloadable Content

Tags: iphone, ipad, uikit, download

Sorry for the silly question, but I am looking at many news apps (The Daily, etc) and they appear to have downloadable Views or something. The interaction with the views seems a lot like UIViews. Are they using downloadable UIViews or WebViews to see that content? If they are using UIViews, how is this done?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "downloadable" views? Do you just mean views whose content is retrieved from the web?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two approaches you can take when you want to display content from a server.

1. Implement your UI using iOS UI components. For that you would use `UIView` as a container for the data, a `UIActivityIndicator` to show that you are downloading the data from the server, either in form of `XML` or `JSON` format. Then you would present those data using iOS UI components such as `UITextArea`, `UILabel`, `UIImageView` and so on.
2. Implement a simple `UIWebView` and give it a url with the content that resides on your web server. The advantage of this solution is that you can manipulate the way the content looks from your server site when the app is already in the App store. You will not be able to do it with the first approach.

Most of the apps use the first approach, but if you don't have much time and want to do it in a dirty fast way use the second approach.

Comment: I guess I am a little confused.  What about any code that needs to be written to handle buttons, any kind of animations, etc?  Is that all part of the JSON file? Do you know of any tutorials on this type of thing?